# Django template generation

Tags: django, django-templates

I am blanking out on this as I have no experience to draw upon to be able to come up with a solution.

That's what my model looks like:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class News(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

I am passing to my template a news object.

What I want the template to do is to loop through this news object, and display an html page that looks like this:

```
Category 1
    headline 1
    headline 2 
    ...
Category 2
    headline 1
    headline 2
    headline 3 
    ...
Category ....
```

And so on for every category in the news object that I passed to the template.

As an example, a category can be 'world news', 'sports' ...
and the headline will be anything that is related to that category

thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to [regroup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) the news queryset by category.

Comment: Thanks a million!! you solved in 1 min what I failed to achieve in 5 hours. I can now call this a day :)